# API Management vs. Service Flow

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-api-management

I have a very basic setup: APIM + SF with WebAPI Stateless Service (Kestrel). Just trying to make this POC work. Unsuccessful so far... :(

Following the available instructions I got to the point, where I am having problems with the APIM inbound policies... 
What am I supposed to use for the  backend-id?
Besides the "servicefabric" one (from examples), I have tried probably all of the options from my "service fabric" instance metadata. It keeps coming back to me with:
"Backend with id 'whatever-I-put-in-here' could not be found."

I would really appreciate if someone could shed some light into what exactly is meant by backend-id=""!

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: The backend-id has to reference a "backend resource" that has been created via the API Management API (or deployment template) as there currently is no UI to create these backend resources.  In the deployment template pointed to by the article the definition of the backend resource is here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-api-management/blob/master/apim.json#L162

Answer (score 1):

The backend-id has to reference a "backend resource" that has been created via the API Management API (or deployment template) as there currently is no UI to create these backend resources.  In the deployment template pointed to by the article the definition of the backend resource is here:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-api-management/blob/master/apim.json#L162

You can use this API call to list the existing backends for your service:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/backends?api-version=2017-03-01
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/backend/listbyservice

Comment: There's also a PowerShell command to create it, but the Azure Portal UI refuses to accept IDs created by it... even with the IDs being valid in both the get-AzureRmApiManagementBackend and resources.azure.com

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/new-azurermapimanagementbackendservicefabric