# Configuring service fabric as API management backend

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-api-management

I'm starting to explore integrating an API management service with a service fabric backend but I can't get it to work.

I have a simple app deployed to a cluster which is exposing one stateless service. I'm trying to configure API management using the few examples I can find, e.g:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-api-management-overview

But I get an error telling me that the given backend-id cannot be found, no matter what I enter.

I have read the response to this question where it's stated that I need to setup a backend resource:
[API Management vs. Service Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457496/api-management-vs-service-flow)

...which links to the template from this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-deploy-api-management

And have tried to extract the 'backends' part but still can't get it to work. Does anyone have a simple example or instructions of how I can setup a backend resource so that i can setup a set-backend-service inbound rule pointing to my service fabric service running in a cluster?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apimService1/backends/sfbackend?api-version=2017-03-01

```
{
  "properties": {
    "description": "Service Fabric Test App 1",
    "protocol": "http",
    "url": "fabric:/mytestapp/mytestservice",
    "properties": {
      "serviceFabricCluster": {
        "managementEndpoints": [
          "https://somecluster.com"
        ],
        "clientCertificatethumbprint": "EBA029198AA3E76EF0D70482626E5BCF148594A6",
        "serverX509Names": [
          {
            "name": "ServerCommonName1",
            "issuerCertificateThumbprint": "IssuerCertificateThumbprint1"
          }
        ],
        "maxPartitionResolutionRetries": 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/backend/createorupdate#apimanagementcreatebackendservicefabric

Answer (score 0):

It seems that creating the backend through ARM templates is the best way to make it work, but give it a try to a command made specifically to create SF Backends in API Management: new-AzureRmApiManagementBackendServiceFabric

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/new-azurermapimanagementbackendservicefabric

I did, but ran into another blocker: the UI refuses to accept the BackendID created in the command. It says the ID is invalid, even considering that the command get-AzureRmApiManagementBackend shows the recently created IDs.

Comment: Hi, I too created SF BackEnd in API Management through .Net SDK and I can see that in Resource Explorer. However, I don't know how to bind that BackEnd to an API in  API Management Service.
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is bit old, I resolved it as following:

```
$apimContext = New-AzureRmApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroupname" -ServiceName "ApiManagementServicename"
$ManagementEndpoints = 'https://xxxxx:19000'
$ServerCertificateThumbprints = 'thumbprint'
$serviceFabric = New-AzureRmApiManagementBackendServiceFabric -ManagementEndpoint $ManagementEndpoints -ClientCertificateThumbprint $ServerCertificateThumbprints -ServerCertificateThumbprint $ServerCertificateThumbprints
$backend = New-AzureRmApiManagementBackend -Context $apimContext -BackendId SFBackEnd -Url 'fabric:/App/Service' -Protocol http -ServiceFabricCluster $serviceFabric -Description "service fabric backend"
```

Then go the Api and under inbound tag put following:

```
<set-backend-service backend-id="SFBackEnd" sf-service-instance-name="fabric:/App/Service" />
```

make sure the url in command "New-AzureRmApiManagementBackend" is same as "sf-service-instance-name"

Cheers